# mysql union all resultado group by

Tags: mysql

tengo esta consulta  mysql con la intencion de unir en una sola tabla el resultado de 5 consultas, pero en el resultado final solo me aparece el resultado del primer select, el resto sale a cero, y no da ningun error

```
select t.a, t.normals, t.sumneto, t.sumdto, t.vtamedia,    
            t.garantia, t.sumnetgar, t.sumdtogar, t.vtamediagar,
                t.errores,  t.sumneterr, t.sumdtoerr, t.vtamediaerr,
                t.reparacions,  t.sumnetrep, t.sumdtorep, t.vtamediarep,
                t.promo1, t.sumnetpromo1, t.sumdtopromo1, t.vtamediapromo1,
                t.promo2, t.sumnetpromo2, t.sumdtopromo2, t.vtamediapromo2 from
(
select encargos.vendedorVta as a, count(*) as normals, sum(encargos.impnetoVta) as sumneto, sum(encargos.impdtoVta) as sumdto, avg(encargos.impnetoVta) as vtamedia,    
                    0 as garantia, 0 as sumnetgar, 0 as sumdtogar, 0 as vtamediagar,
                    0 as errores,  0 as sumneterr, 0 as sumdtoerr, 0 as vtamediaerr,
                    0 as reparacions,  0 as sumnetrep, 0 as sumdtorep, 0 as vtamediarep,
                    0 as promo1, 0 as sumnetpromo1, 0 as sumdtopromo1, 0 as vtamediapromo1,
                    0 as promo2, 0 as sumnetpromo2, 0 as sumdtopromo2, 0 as vtamediapromo2
from encargos 
where encargos.fechaVta between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-21' and encargos.promocionVta=0
group by encargos.vendedorVta
union all
select encargos.vendedorVta as a, 0 as normals, 0 as sumneto, 0 as sumdto, 0 as vtamedia,    
                    count(*) as garantia, sum(encargos.impnetoVta) as sumnetgar, sum(encargos.impdtoVta) as sumdtogar, avg(encargos.impnetoVta) as vtamediagar,    
                    0 as errores,  0 as sumneterr, 0 as sumdtoerr, 0 as vtamediaerr,
                    0 as reparacions,  0 as sumnetrep, 0 as sumdtorep, 0 as vtamediarep,
                    0 as promo1, 0 as sumnetpromo1, 0 as sumdtopromo1, 0 as vtamediapromo1,
                    0 as promo2, 0 as sumnetpromo2, 0 as sumdtopromo2, 0 as vtamediapromo2
from encargos 
where encargos.fechaVta between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-21' and encargos.promocionVta=0
group by encargos.vendedorVta
union all
select encargos.vendedorVta as a,  0 as normals, 0 as sumneto, 0 as sumdto, 0 as vtamedia,    
                                     0 as garantia, 0 as sumnetgar, 0 as sumdtogar, 0 as vtamediagar,    
                                    count(*) as errores, sum(encargos.impnetoVta) as sumneterr, sum(encargos.impdtoVta) as sumdtoerr, avg(encargos.impnetoVta) as vtamediaerr,
                                    0 as reparacions,  0 as sumnetrep, 0 as sumdtorep, 0 as vtamediarep,
                                    0 as promo1, 0 as sumnetpromo1, 0 as sumdtopromo1, 0 as vtamediapromo1,
                                    0 as promo2, 0 as sumnetpromo2, 0 as sumdtopromo2, 0 as vtamediapromo2
from encargos  
where encargos.fechaVta between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-21' and encargos.promocionVta=3
group by encargos.vendedorVta
union all
select encargos.vendedorVta as a,  0 as normals, 0 as sumneto, 0 as sumdto, 0 as vtamedia,    
                                     0 as garantia, 0 as sumnetgar, 0 as sumdtogar, 0 as vtamediagar,    
                                     0 as errores, 0 as sumneterr, 0 as sumdtoerr, 0 as vtamediaerr,
                                     count(*) as reparacions,  sum(encargos.impnetoVta) as sumnetrep, sum(encargos.impdtoVta) as sumdtorep, avg(encargos.impnetoVta) as vtamediarep,
                                    0 as promo1, 0 as sumnetpromo1, 0 as sumdtopromo1, 0 as vtamediapromo1,
                                    0 as promo2, 0 as sumnetpromo2, 0 as sumdtopromo2, 0 as vtamediapromo2

from encargos  
where encargos.fechaVta between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-21' and encargos.promocionVta=3
group by encargos.vendedorVta
union all
select encargos.vendedorVta as a,  0 as normals, 0 as sumneto, 0 as sumdto, 0 as vtamedia,    
                                     0 as garantia, 0 as sumnetgar, 0 as sumdtogar, 0 as vtamediagar,    
                                     0 as errores, 0 as sumneterr, 0 as sumdtoerr, 0 as vtamediaerr,
                                     0 as reparacions,  0 as sumnetrep, 0 as sumdtorep, 0 as vtamediarep,
                                     count(*) as promo1,  sum(encargos.impnetoVta) as sumnetpromo1, sum(encargos.impdtoVta) as sumdtopromo1, avg(encargos.impnetoVta) as vtamediapromo1,
                                     0 as promo2, 0 as sumnetpromo2, 0 as sumdtopromo2, 0 as vtamediapromo2
from encargos  
where encargos.fechaVta between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-21' and encargos.promocionVta>3 and encargos.encargopralVta = 'S'
group by encargos.vendedorVta
union all
select encargos.vendedorVta as a,  0 as normals, 0 as sumneto, 0 as sumdto, 0 as vtamedia,    
                                     0 as garantia, 0 as sumnetgar, 0 as sumdtogar, 0 as vtamediagar,    
                                     0 as errores, 0 as sumneterr, 0 as sumdtoerr, 0 as vtamediaerr,
                                     0 as reparacions,  0 as sumnetrep, 0 as sumdtorep, 0 as vtamediarep,
                                     0 as promo1, 0 as sumnetpromo1, 0 as sumdtopromo1, 0 as vtamediapromo1,
                                     count(*) as promo2,  sum(encargos.impnetoVta) as sumnetpromo2, sum(encargos.impdtoVta) as sumdtopromo2, avg(encargos.impnetoVta) as vtamediapromo2
from encargos  
where encargos.fechaVta between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-21' and encargos.promocionVta>3 and encargos.encargopralVta = 'N'
group by encargos.vendedorVta
) t
group by t.a
order by t.a
```

Comment: tú mismo la estás metiendo como 0 en los demás selects 0 as...